# Is there any function calculate duration in minutes between two datetimes values?

Tags: python

This is my dataframe.

```
Start_hour        End_date  
     23:58:00        00:26:00
     23:56:00        00:01:00
     23:18:00        23:36:00
```

How can I get in a new column the difference (in minutes) between these two columns?

Comment: yes: dt1 - dt2 gives you a timedelta and if has a .minutes attribute if not mistaken

Comment: What happened when you tried to compute a difference in the normal way, i.e., by subtracting?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> 
>>> before = datetime.now()
>>> print('wait for more than 1 minute')
wait for more than 1 minute
>>> after = datetime.now()
>>> td = after - before
>>> 
>>> td
datetime.timedelta(seconds=98, microseconds=389121)
>>> td.total_seconds()
98.389121
>>> td.total_seconds() / 60
1.6398186833333335
```

Then you can round it or use it as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Start_hour': ['23:58:00', '23:56:00', '23:18:00'],
   'End_date': ['00:26:00', '00:01:00', '23:36:00']}
) 
df['Start_hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_hour'])
df['End_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_date']) 
df['diff'] = df.apply(
   lambda row: (row['End_date']-row['Start_hour']).seconds / 60,
   axis=1
) 
print(df)

           Start_hour            End_date  diff
0 2021-03-29 23:58:00 2021-03-29 00:26:00  28.0
1 2021-03-29 23:56:00 2021-03-29 00:01:00   5.0
2 2021-03-29 23:18:00 2021-03-29 23:36:00  18.0
```

You can also rearrange your dates as string again if you like:

```
df['Start_hour'] = df['Start_hour'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
df['End_date'] = df['End_date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Start_hour  End_date  diff
0   23:58:00  00:26:00  28.0
1   23:56:00  00:01:00   5.0
2   23:18:00  23:36:00  18.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```py
df['interval'] = df['End_date'] - df['Start_hour']
df['interval'][df['End_date'] < df['Start_hour']] += timedelta(hours=24)
```

Why so:

You probably trying to solve the problem that your `Start_hout` and `End_date` values sometimes belong to a different days, and that's why you can't just substutute one from the other.

It your time window **never exceeds 24 hours interval**, you could use some modular arithmetic to deal with `23:59:59` - `00:00:00` border:

- if `End_date < Start_hour`, this always means `End_date` belongs to a next day
- this implies, if `End_date - Start_hour < 0` then we should add `24 hours` to `End_date` to find the actual difference
  The final formula is:

```py
if rec['Start_hour'] < rec['End_date']:
    offset = 0
else:
    offset = timedelta(hours=24)

rec['delta'] = offset + rec['End_date'] - rec['Start_hour']
```

To do the same with `pandas.DataFrame` we need to change code accordingly. And
that's how we get the snippet from the beginning of the answer.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Start_hour': datetime(1, 1, 1, 23, 58, 0), 'End_date': datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 26, 0)},
    {'Start_hour': datetime(1, 1, 1, 23, 58, 0), 'End_date': datetime(1, 1, 1, 23, 59, 0)},
])

# ...
df['interval'] = df['End_date'] - df['Start_hour']
df['interval'][df['End_date'] < df['Start_hour']] += timedelta(hours=24)


> df
            Start_hour             End_date        interval
0  0001-01-01 23:58:00  0001-01-01 00:26:00 0 days 00:28:00
1  0001-01-01 23:58:00  0001-01-01 23:59:00 0 days 00:01:00
```